# Cannot update Win 10 to v1909 Realtek Bluetooth driver has to be updated

Tags: windows-10

Windows update is stuck telling me I need to update my Realtek Bluetooth driver software.

My problem is that I do not have the Realtek Bluetooth radio listed in device manager. The only Realtek hardware I have is HD Audio, which has been updated to the latest drivers.

Is this a known issue? Or more to the point: is there a way to tell Update to simply update anyway and I'll accept that I'll never get to use the Realtek Bluetooth radio (which I don't have anyway) again?

Comment: Found this article about the problem: https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-blocks-windows-10-1909-update-on-pcs-with-old-realtek-bluetooth-radio-drivers/ Is one up to transform it into a good answer?

Answer (score 8):

Ran into this problem also, complaining about old Realtek BT drivers but none installed.

First check for non-present devices in Device Manager by enabling hidden items under View/Show hidden devices. If you still don't see your bluetooth device listed, you may have an orphaned driver file like I did.

Check your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` folder for the file `RtkBtfilter.sys`.
An old Realtek bluetooth driver, not being used but detected by the updater

Deleted the file and update was able to continue.

There was nothing logged in the CompatData().xml files as suggested to check here:

https://www.howtogeek.com/416169/how-to-fix-what-needs-your-attention-windows-10-setup-errors/

(I guess because it wasn't installed nor was there any inf file for it)

Comment: deleting RtkBtfilter.sys solved this issue for me. Thanks for sharing this tip

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your Realtek Bluetooth driver is too outdated,
as described in the Microsoft article
[Updating to a new version of Windows 10 on devices with some driver versions for Realtek Bluetooth radios](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4529832/updating-to-windows-10-version-1903-on-devices-with-some-driver-versio).

A workaround is found in the article
[Microsoft Removes Windows 10 1909 Realtek Driver Update Block](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-removes-windows-10-1909-realtek-driver-update-block/)
:

- Download these two Realtek Bluetooth radio drivers:
  [Driver 1](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2019/01/f2748416-7753-49c6-9185-56f4986f490b_e98e0d664b7e874011b8e3752046ca61f3475295.cab)
  and
  [Driver 2](http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2018/11/068de0d6-6ac2-473a-8cbd-bd449cd5c97c_942eec5828662eecc6b98cc2706658bf2433717c.cab)
- Using File Explorer, double-click both and extract their contents
  into the same folder, but in two different sub-folders
- Start Device Manager
- Find and expand "Bluetooth"
- Right-click the Realtek device and select Update Driver
- Select "Browse my computer for driver software" and position to the
  above folder
- It should find the drivers and install them
- Select Close.

Windows 10 version 1909 may now agree to install (if it finds the hardware
acceptable).

Comment: OP clearly stated that they do not have a Realtek bluetooth device.  This answer only works if you actually have a realtek bluetooth device listed in device manager.  BAM has the right answer.

Comment: @J...: You misread the post. The problem is that the device is *not listed*.

Comment: It's not listed because it is not physically present.  The workaround you've shown assumes (and requires) that the hardware is actually present.

Comment: @J...: Where does it say it's not present?

Comment: The only realtek hardware they have is HD Audio (third sentence).  The question asks how they can force the update and ignore the driver prerequisite for a radio `which I don't have anyway` (last sentence).

Comment: @J...: The paragraph seems to say that he would like to use Realtek "again". The poster was the first to upvote this answer.

Comment: It's a long sentence, perhaps difficult to parse if you're not a native speaker(?)  `is there a way to tell Update to simply update anyway and I'll accept that I'll never get to use the Realtek Bluetooth radio (which I don't have anyway) again?`  OP is asking if they can force the update despite the conflict, accepting that the nonpresent bluetooth device would consequently not be operable if it existed (which it doesn't). In any case, the KB above is linked directly in the dialog from the updater when this fault is encountered so presumably anyone asking here would already have tried that.

Comment: @J...: Better stop there, before getting into insults. There are many ways of understanding a post, and the only final judge is the poster.

Comment: Wasn't meant as an insult, apologies. I grant you the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a known issue?

It's a known issue for multiple versions of Windows 10 (1809,1903 and 1909).

> is there a way to tell Update to simply update anyway, and I'll accept that I'll never get to use the Realtek Bluetooth radio (which I don't have anyway) again?

The issue surrounding the driver is an issue that will block the installation of any of these versions. The solution to this problem is to simply update the driver.

> Unable to discover or connect to Bluetooth devices using some Realtek
>   adapters Microsoft has identified compatibility issues with some
>   driver versions for Bluetooth radios made by Realtek. To safeguard
>   your update experience, we have applied a compatibility hold on
>   devices with affected driver versions for Realtek Bluetooth radios
>   from being offered Windows 10, version 1903 or Windows Server, version
>
> Resolution: This issue was resolved with an updated driver for the
>   affected Realtek Bluetooth radio and the safeguard hold has been
>   removed. Please note, it can take up to 48 hours before you can update
>   to offered Windows 10, version 1909 or Windows 10, version 1903.
>   1903 until the driver has been updated.

Source: [Known Issues for Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1909#known-issues)

> Microsoft has identified compatibility issues with some driver
>   versions for Bluetooth radios made by Realtek. You will need to update
>   to driver version 1.5.1012 or later to remove this safeguard hold. 
>   Any earlier version of the driver is affected by this issue.
>
> To safeguard your update experience, we have applied a compatibility
>   hold on devices with affected driver versions for Realtek Bluetooth
>   radios from installing Windows 10, version 1909 or Windows 10, version
>   1903 until the driver has been updated.
>
> 1. Download both of the Realtek Bluetooth radio drivers to your preferred folder: [Driver 1](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2019/01/f2748416-7753-49c6-9185-56f4986f490b_e98e0d664b7e874011b8e3752046ca61f3475295.cab), [Driver 2](http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2018/11/068de0d6-6ac2-473a-8cbd-bd449cd5c97c_942eec5828662eecc6b98cc2706658bf2433717c.cab).  Note We recommend
>      downloading them to your Documents folder. Open File Explorer. If
>      there is no file explorer icon in the task bar, select the search box
>      and enter file explorer and select it.
> 2. Within File Explorer, go the the Documents folder or the folder you downloaded the drivers to.
> 3. Find and double click or double tap on the file named **068de0d6-6ac2-473a-8cbd-bd449cd5c97c_942eec5828662eecc6b98cc2706658bf2433717c.cab**
> 4. Select CTRL+a on the keyboard. This should select all of the files Right click or long press on any of the files and select Extract.
> 5. Select the New folder button and rename it Realtek Bluetooth. Select the Extract button.
> 6. In File Explorer, select the back  button to go to the location you downloaded the drivers into.
> 7. Find and double click or double tap on the file named **f2748416-7753-49c6-9185-56f4986f490b_e98e0d664b7e874011b8e3752046ca61f3475295.cab**
> 8. Select CTRL+a on the keyboard. This should select all of the files Right click or long press on any of the files and select Extract.
> 9. If you are in the folder named Realtek Bluetooth, then select the New folder button and type Realtek Bluetooth 2.
> 10. Select the Extract button.
> 11. In the search box on the taskbar, enter device manager, then select Device Manager. Find Bluetooth and expand it.
> 12. Find the Realtek device and right-click or long press on it.
> 13. Select Update Driver from the context menu.
> 14. Select the Browse my computer for driver software button. It should default to your Documents folder, if this is where you saved
>       the drivers then just select the Next button.  If you did not save the
>       drivers to your Documents folder, select the Browse button and find
>       the folder you downloaded the drivers to and select OK.
>
> 13.It should now find the updated drivers and install them.  Wait for this to complete and select Close.

Source: [Updating to a new version of Windows 10 on devices with some driver versions for Realtek Bluetooth radios](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4529832/updating-to-windows-10-version-1903-on-devices-with-some-driver-versio)

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth module may be attached to the Audio card to save money. Update your Audio Driver (and also all other drivers) and then run the Windows Update again.

Answer (score -1):

If you face difficulty finding updates for your drivers, try third party applications to do those for you. Finding the exact device in the Device Manager can be troublesome sometimes.

I use [Intel Driver & Support Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html). Alternatively, if you use a laptop, you may find a software on the OEM's website that does the job.