# My PC isn't updating from 1803 to 1903

Tags: windows, desktop-computer, windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1903

I cannot seem to update, and using the Windows 10 Update Assistant reports that Windows is installed in an unsupported directory, and it cannot proceed to update without clearing all of my data (PC specs are below).

I tried clearing the Windows update cache, and it redownloaded through Windows update, and it rebooted, and got to 18% and then rebooted, and then got to the boot screen and said Updating your system, and at 5% it said FATAL ERROR and an error code. This happens every once in a while now, when it attempts to update.

I tried *all* troubleshooters, everything, even using an MSU file to update, and using the installation media to update, but nothing worked.

I use UltraUXThemePatcher for my UX theme, as I use a custom dark theme, and I have some registry tweaks like no lock screen, dark Alt Tab backgrounds. I use Listary for search. I have a registry tweak to set default program files folders to my D: drive.

I am on Windows 10 1803, 1809 refuses to install, and I don't have a dedicated DVD/ROM drive.

I will be happy to respond in this forum.

Specs:

- CPU: Intel Core i7 7740x
- Mobo: Asus TUF Mark 2
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 3GB (ASUS Geforce GTX 1060 3GB)
- RAM: 16GB 4x4 Corsair Vengeance LPX
- SSD: 240GB M.2 SSD - it isn't well-known. I got it from Amazon & it seemed legit, it was 6GbPS
- HDD: 2TB Seagate Baracuda
- PSU: Corsair SF Series Modular SF600 ATX Power Supply (600 watts) (80 plus platinum)
- Cooler: DeepCool CAPTAIN 240 EX White AIO (used on a 2066 socket)
- Case: NZXT S340VR Elite

Comment: "I will be happy to respond in this forum, go ahead and make me look dumb ;)" The SE network is **not** a forum. It is a collection of question and answer sites. Please bear that in mind when you use the sites.

Comment: "I have a registry tweak to set default program files folders to my D: drive" Try setting this back to the correct place.

Comment: Which error code?

Comment: [Resolve Windows 10 upgrade errors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors) contain a link to a tool that will help you diagnose the failure contained within `..\pather\setupact.log` and `..\pather\setuperr.log`.

Comment: @GameGlitz After additional research, based on the fact your motherboard has a Realtek audio device, the problem is due to the Realtek audio driver being incompatible with 1903.  Thus this question is a duplicate of [Cannot update Win 10 to v1909 Realtek Bluetooth driver has to be updated](https://superuser.com/questions/1502848/cannot-update-win-10-to-v1909-realtek-bluetooth-driver-has-to-be-updated/1502866#1502866).  **The driver compatibility issue affects 1809, 1903, and 1909 so disregard the question title.**

Comment: "1809 refuses to install," More details please.

Comment: @Ramhound First of all, your kind solution is not related, as I have already successfully got it running.

Comment: @harrymc For your question, it did not provide one.

Comment: @Moab I have already provided more info.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the info about it not being a forum. Also, you were on the right track about setting the folder back to C: drive, I will explain what I did in the next comment.

Comment: So, here is what I did: First, I set my Program Files DIR to C: from D: and booted into Windows PE. Then, I went into CMD and used DISM to image the C: drive, as a  failsafe. Then, I applied the image with DISM, but to a folder called Windows.TEMP and that was the fresh install, then I modified the registry of it, followed by adding a boot entry. I then booted to it and skipped OOBE, and booted back into WinPE. I then copied everything from the old Windows folder that I knew was not related to Windows itself, and moved the new install. It worked out, I patched UXTheme and it was upgraded!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because according to most recent comment they have figured out the solution to their problem themselves

Comment: @GameGlitz - We won't know if it's related since you took nearly 2 months to respond to my comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot update Win 10 to v1909 Realtek Bluetooth driver has to be updated](https://superuser.com/questions/1502848/cannot-update-win-10-to-v1909-realtek-bluetooth-driver-has-to-be-updated)

Comment: @GameGlitz Windows would have logged the error code in one of the system or installer log files.  I'm assuming from your above comment that you have a non-supported configuration, from the Windows installer's generic view, since you have `%ProgramFiles%`/`%ProgramFiles(x86)%` on a drive other than `C:` _(hardcoded system directories like this are hardcoded all throughout the registry and contain hardlinks)_?   The most likely issue is one of two, or a combo of both; unsupported system directory configuration or corrupted [modified] system files in `%WinDir%` from the UI patcher _(cont'd)_

Comment: _(Cont'd)_ For the UI patcher, it's not as simple as restoring the original `.dll`s, as the originals may no longer match the expected hashes of those files if they were updated in a Windows Update or if the hashes do not match those contained within the Component Store (`%WinDir%\WinSxS`).  If you encounter the issue again, it would be beneficial to rule this scenario out by performing the following, in the order listed, before updating: `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` > `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` > Reboot > `SFC /ScanNow` > Reboot > Retry install.

Comment: I already know that, as the hashes are newer due to the new theming of v1909, I have already patched.

Answer (score 4):

I was kind of waiting for this question.

While the Bluetooth adaptor is *one* thing that does this, the windows update process checks for certain things then fails if they are not there. This is stored in registry (boo!) and the tool that reads it was a little hard to find.

MS has a tool for [advanced users called SetupDiag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag) that looks through the logs and tells you *precisely* why newer versions of windows isn't running a feature update. In my case it was backup software (macrium) that had changed a registry entry (related to volume shadow copies)  and didn't reset it once uninstalled . It also tells you *what to do*.

Unlike the update troubleshooter, it dosen't run through a series of useless steps - it tells you what's wrong, and expects you to fix it. Which is much better.

Comment: Can you name the offending backup software? It may make it easier to google this.

Comment: Well, the point here was its a generic solution.  Added more details, but I don't particularly blame macrium. Actually the point was to have this somewhere I could find it, next time it bites me :D

Comment: Important to point out this tool only works for more recent versions of Windows 10.  It absolutely will fail if you run it on Windows 10 version 1507.  The tool requires you to be running a version released after Microsoft improved the upgrade process.  This would have been around Windows 10 version 1703.  I have written about my struggles to go from Windows 10 version 1507 to Windows 10 version 1803 last year.  I documented the diagnostic tool I suggested in a comment back in November.

Comment: I think I used it on a stuck 1703 install - seems like something they should have in the docs

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - It's not that the tool will no parse the relevant logs, it's that it will determine the incorrect conclusion, in my case 1507 to 1803 was possible but 1507 to 1511 was possible.  Which is how I concluded the tool isn't helpful until you get to a version with the improved upgrade process.

Comment: "With the release of Windows 10, version 2004, SetupDiag is included with Windows Setup" (in C:\$Windows.~bt\Sources).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new here, didn't realise I could just answer my own question, I have already solved it so here is my solution:

---

So, here is what I did: First, I set my Program Files DIR to C: from D: and booted into Windows PE. Then, I went into CMD and used DISM to image the C: drive, as a failsafe. Then, I applied the image with DISM, but to a folder called Windows.TEMP and that was the fresh install, then I modified the registry of it, followed by adding a boot entry. I then booted to it and skipped OOBE, and booted back into WinPE. I then copied everything from the old Windows folder that I knew was not related to Windows itself, and moved the new install. It worked out, I patched UXTheme and it was upgraded!

---

Anyway, if you have the same issue and the solution that I did doesn't work for you, tag me in a new post and I might be able to help.